# Opencart 3.0.2.0 Custum Layout

Tags: css, twig, opencart, opencart-3

Good afternoon
Is there anyone who can help me.
I have been trying for a while, but i do not get it done.
I use OpenCart 3.0.2.0 and would like a different kind of Layout.
I would like to select per banner whether it is left, center or right.
As soon as I choose left or right, this applies to the entire page.

Here is a layout I want:

[image]

This is what I want.

Can anybody help me with the code? And with file to edit.

Answer (score 1):

I can guide you to a HTML/CSS/LESS code I have built and you can take an example from that should you wish.

I used lesscss.org, and the npm package less-watch-compiler.

https://github.com/mabbashm110/Sprint-Challenge--Responsive-Less

Also check this video out on how to create a custom theme on Open cart: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqTstomXZiM

Let me know if you need help understanding it.

Comment: Thanx for the reply.I already used the tutoriol in the YouTube video and it works perfect. But after building the theme like in the video it stil is not possible to edit the themes like i want.

Comment: Thanx for the reply.I already used the tutoriol in the YouTube video and it works perfect. But after building the theme like in the video it stil is not possible to edit the themes like i want.I already edit the css to change the them colors and worked with twig files to delete the descreption from the index page.But i want to be able the have the choice every line ( Extension or Banner ) to have info left center or right and the next diferent.I don't know if i can use LESS on opencart ? And i also don't know what file is the layout edit file for opencart.Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think You have to modify controller and pass data to twig.
after modify twig file code according to your need.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not a coder, if someone can help me on the right track, that's fine. I'd like to know which files to edit. I understand that this site is for coders and not for my but on the forum no one tels me which files determine the margins for the layout.